# RMS Current through output diode in a flyback transformer with multiple outputs

Tags: transformer, flyback

I clearly do not understand where does this formula comes from ... (I did not find it on internet)
$$
\mathrm{
I_{diode_{rms}} = \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{A²}{3}}}{\sqrt{1-D}}*I_{out_{avg}}
}
$$

where Iout is the output current drawn by the load, D is the duty cycle and A is defined as follow (it seems to be the transfer function of a flyback working in CCM but it is not exactly right) :

$$
\mathrm{
A = \frac{(DVin)^2}{2L_{primary}P_{in}F_{sw}}
}
$$

where Fsw is the switching frequency of the flyback, Lprimary is the primary inductance of the flyback, Pin is the input power.

If anybody is able to demonstrate this formula even for a simple transformer with only one output,  it would be nice !

Thank you very much and have a nice day !

Comment: Where did you find the formulas if not on the internet?

Comment: A = power efficiency of the flyback converter FYI

Comment: This is coming from the office, but it has been probably found on internet or in a book. The man who wrote it is probably retired.

Comment: I agree with you at least for a DCM converter ! I did not think that it is equal to the efficiency for a converter operating in CCM

Comment: I cannot answer that - you have formulas made by some guy who might be in-contactable and therefore there is little go on. BTW, it's "current through" and "voltage across". Not helpful to you I know LOL.

Comment: Thank you ! I am completely bad in english ... I think that It will be hard to answer to this question ... I will probably close it

Comment: Maybe wait for Mr @VerbalKint - he might know or recognize something that might help?

Comment: "This is my last hope" :D

Comment: Yes, I am not yet roasted by the hot summer in France and I gave an answer below : )

Comment: Not this year :D but the next year ? You may consider buying a house in Britanny ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where this formula comes from and I have never seen it. I derived the formula for the secondary-side diode rms current in [my book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071823468) published in 2014, page 755. I have built a quick Mathcad sheet to test it against your formula. This is a 72-W ac-dc adapter, no leakage inductance (otherwise the peak sec. current would be reduced) and low conduction losses in the MOSFET:

[image]

So for a 120-V input voltage, the sheet computes a peak current of 2.15 A and a valley current of 0.95 A in the primary. The rms current in the diode is computed to slightly less than 5 A.

To test these results, I have captured a quick flyback circuit with SIMPLIS and ran a simulation:

[image]

Once the simulation is done, pressing F3 in the curve windows gives you the diode rms current:

[image]

The simulated current is 4.98 A, very close to what the calculation gives. If I now use the formula you mentioned:

[image]

As you can see, there is no significant error with the simulation and my Mathcad sheet. So your formula is correct and elegantly arranged : )

One way to get the diode rms current is to determine the ripple in the magnetizing inductance of the flyback converter. You can follow the calculation details in a [series of articles](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/1010/articles/H2PowerToday1010_design_ONSemi.pdf?NOREDIR=1) I published in [How2Power](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/index.php) in 2010. For a multi-output converter, precisely calculating all rms current can be somewhat adventurous considering all the leakage inductances at play which heavily distort waveforms (see [here](https://ecee.colorado.edu/%7Erwe/references/PESC98.pdf) for the cantilever transformer model and Fig. 9 for the sec. waveforms).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your simulation ! Your formula is only valid for a flyback operating in CCM, isn't it ? Apparently the formula that I gave you works also in DCM. I will take a look on it and see how to demonstrate it ! And I will do some simulations with LTspice (or SIMPLIS ??)

Comment: Yes, the (1-D) factor only works in CCM as, in DCM, you have the dead-time \$d_3T_{SW}\$ which must be evaluated to get \$d_2T_{SW}\$, the time duration during which the current circulates in the output diode.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :D